# Demystifying the Virtual Keyboard and Touchpad in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I'm new to Windows development, and am looking for assistance on where to get started for a particular project.

In short, I want to create a windowed application that allows a user to send keyboard and mouse inputs to another application, by interacting with various UI controls via touch.  Essentially a custom on-screen keyboard/touchpad that can be used for sending keyboard-shortcuts to other applications.

There are two applications in Windows 10 that perform *exactly* the way I would want my new app to - the On-Screen Keyboard and Touchpad:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4337906/windows-10-open-the-on-screen-touchpad

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10762/windows-use-on-screen-keyboard

At the most basic level, I want to define my own interface (or allow the end user to define their own), and use the same code that the onscreen keyboard/touchpad are using for handling touch events and injecting inputs into the system.

I'm uncertain at what level I would need to start to get the functionality I need - UWP?  WPF?  C++?

If anyone has any insight into how the on-screen utilities were built, I think that would give me an excellent head start.

Comment: OSK is a native Win32 (64-bit) application written in C++, the other one (Microsoft Text Input Application) is a UWP application

Comment: @Castorix - What about the on-screen touchpad?